# Does the answerer lose award/points when I first accepted his answer and then changed my mind and accepted another one

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, accepted-answer

As the title, does the answerer lose award/points when I first accepted his answer and then changed my mind and accepted another one?

I got three good answer, the second one I liked more and accepted it. Later the third answer came and it was so perfect (better than all previous) that I accepted it too. The question is, do both answerers get  +15 for their accepted answers after all. Because I understand the the last answer I accepted definitely gets +15, I can see it as green tick moved to it. But what for the scoring of the first answerer with regards to acceptance, will he see any change in reputation scores after I changed my mind?

Sorry for complicated thing? I also understand that it most likely has been already asked and answered but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Have a look at [What is reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  If you unaccept an answer the originally accepted answer loses the 15 points.  However if it happens in the same day the user won't see the gain or the loss (they'll be combined to a 0).  He won't lose any in total-  just the amount he gained from the original accept, so don't be afraid to change if a better answer emerges.